# Error: Could not find or load main class on 32 bit windows 7 machine

Tags: java, runtime-error

We have a java application, for which we have generated a jar file. We are using the following command to run:

```
somepath\dist\jre\bin\java -Dname=xyz -classpath apache-mime4j-0.6.jar;commons-codec-1.7.jar;myApp.jar;java-json.jar;log4j-1.2.17.jar;sqlite4java.jar com.xyz.myApp arg1 arg2
```

When running on 32-bit windows computer we are getting `Error: Could not find or load main class` The same command and jar files work fine with 64-bit computers.

Running with -Xdiag gives:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.myApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Any solution or help in debugging is appreciated.

Comment: `-Dname=xyz-classpath` should be `-Dname=xyz -classpath`. Classes should start with an uppercase letter. The error you posted doesn't match the command, since it complains about the class `myApp`, and not about  `com.xyz.myApp`.

Comment: Are you sure there is a Class called "om.xyz.myApp" in that jar? In the right folder? Open it (it is a .zip file) and verify

Comment: This does not look like it has anything to do with 32 vs 64 bit machine architecture. Can you run a "hello world" program on that machine?

Comment: @JBNizet It is a copy paste error. I will update the command.

Comment: We have check the package name and class name for any error. The jar files are proper. We are able to run on 64 bit machines without any problem @keuleJ

Comment: Post the real command, the real error message, and the real content of the real myApp.jar (i.e. the real output of `jar tvf myApp.jar`).

Comment: @JBNizet The jar file got corrupted while transfering to the 32 bit machine(pen drive had a h/w issue or a virus not sure).  I was able to run the application. Thank you.